# What are the implications of using aggregated data in lme4 for GLMMs?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm working with the `lme4` package in `R`, looking to fit GLMM models. For the proprietary data I'm working with, my dataset can often be quite large. When dealing with bernoulli response variables, I'm in the habit of aggregating my data (see sample code). I'm wondering how this effects the model algorithm. What are the affects of "lowering the number of observations" to below the number of random effects? If I can fit the model on non-aggregated data, shouldn't I be able to fit it on the aggregated data? So why am I able to fit `model`, but not `model_agg`? I implement a "hacky" "solution" in the code below - is this a permissible thing to do?

Note: I'm not too worried about the warning message at the end of the code block - this isn't the data I'm working with. I AM interested in understanding the "number of observations" error.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)
hdp <- read.csv('http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hdp.csv')
head(hdp)
#   DID CancerStage remission
# 1   1          II         0
# 2   1          II         0
# 3   1          II         0
# 4   1           I         0
# 5   1          II         0
# 6   1           I         0


model <- glmer(remission ~ 1 + CancerStage + (1 + CancerStage | DID), data = hdp, 
           family = 'binomial', control = glmerControl(optimizer = 'bobyqa'))

hdp_agg <- hdp %>% 
    group_by(DID, CancerStage) %>% 
    summarize(y   = sum(remission), 
              num = n())
head(hdp_agg)
# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: DID
# 
#   DID CancerStage y num
# 1   1           I 0   9
# 2   1          II 0  16
# 3   1         III 0   2
# 4   1          IV 0   1
# 5   2           I 6  13
# 6   2          II 4  11


model_agg <- glmer(cbind(y, num - y) ~ 1 + CancerStage + (1 + CancerStage | DID), data = hdp_agg, 
                family = 'binomial', control = glmerControl(optimizer = 'bobyqa'))
# Error: number of observations (=1507) < number of random effects (=1628) for term (1 + CancerStage | DID); 
# the random-effects parameters are probably unidentifiable

hdp_agg2 <- with(hdp_agg, as.tbl(
    data.frame(DID         = rep(unique(DID), each = n_distinct(CancerStage)), 
               CancerStage = rep(unique(CancerStage), times = n_distinct(DID))))) %>% 
    left_join(hdp_agg, by = c('DID', 'CancerStage')) %>%
    mutate(y   = ifelse(is.na(y), 0, y), 
           num = ifelse(is.na(num), 0, num))

model_agg <- glmer(cbind(y, num - y) ~ 1 + CancerStage + (1 + CancerStage | DID), data = hdp_agg2, 
                   family = 'binomial', control = glmerControl(optimizer = 'bobyqa'))
# Warning messages:
# 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
#   Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00275742 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
# 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
#   Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
#  - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
#  - Rescale variables?
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. In *general* aggregation is always a good idea.  I'm not quite sure why it's not working here -- I would think that `lme4` would automatically drop unused levels of the interaction (which isn't happening here ...) I will investigate ...